# Issue in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In the below code i have a textbox in which when i enter numeric it should alert that only alphabets are allowed.In which i get the regular expresion and spilt it and store in an array and for loop it and check the regular expression that i enter in my textbox.Pls help to solve the issue.

```
<input type="text" id="check" onblur="validate()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {

        var hiddenValue = new RegExp( "[A-Z]~~[a-z]");
        // var val = document.getElementById("check").value;
        var mySplitResult = new Array();
        mySplitResult = hiddenValue.split("~~");
        for (i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++) {
            document.write("<br /> Array[" + i + " ]= " + mySplitResult[i]);

            if (mySplitResult.test(document.getElementById("check").value)) {
                alert('check');
                return false;
            }
    }


}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't use `split()` on a `RegExp`, it's only for strings. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: yes you could just write this as mySplitResult = [new RegExp("[A-Z]"), new RegExp("[a-z]")];

Comment: how to validate if it is a string

Comment: @user3278874 if its a string then first you split it.. then you turn each part into a regexp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test that an input is all letters:

```
if (!document.getElementById("check").value.test(/^[a-z]+$/i)) {
    alert ("Only letters are permitted");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle. Will check that only letters are in the textbox otherwise alert.

http://jsfiddle.net/2EDYV/2/

```
function validate() {
    var result = /^([a-zA-Z]+)$/.test(document.getElementById("check").value);
    if (!result) {
        alert('numeric value found');
    }
}
```